# strange problem with numbered lists

Tags: support

I have always had so trouble getting lists to number but today had a problem with this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58451/where-does-the-style-manager-store-the-files-in-and-why-does-the-style-manager-d/58502#58502)
I created my numbered list and it was fine 1 -4. 
then I added pictures between  and it began renumbering with 1 .
then I went to manually make it a 3 and it said 3 in my text box but displayed a 1. in the answer.
Then I selected the number and clicked the numbered list icon (I thought I remembered using that before and it just negated the numbered list) but it added another number below.
Is this a bug or am I using numbered lists wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bug.  You maintain the numbering by indenting the material within each numbered portion.  I fixed your answer for you so you can see how it's done.